# Как изменить папку загрузки? Google Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-extension

При скачивании файла определяю имя файла вот так:

```
chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename.addListener
```

Но требуется изменить папку сохранения файла. Собственно вопрос: как можно это сделать?

Answer (score 0):

Колбэк `onDeterminingFilename` вызывается с двумя аргументами: объект загрузки и функция `suggest`, которая позволяет установить относительный путь загрузки файлов. 

При этому API не позволяет выйти на уровень выше, а только создавать подпапки в основной директории загрузок.

Пример:

```js
chrome.downloads.onDeterminingFilename.addListener(function(item, suggest) {
    suggest({
        filename: 'my-folder/' + item.filename
    });
});
```